# minimizing the mean squared error?

Tags: estimation, estimators

I'm reading this book "[Applied Optimal Estimation"](http://www.amazon.ca/Applied-Estimation-Analytic-Sciences-Corporation/dp/0262570483) by A. Gelb. In the example 1.0-1, there are two measurements $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ with some noise for measuring $x$ as following 
$$
z_{1} = x + v_{1} \\
z_{2} = x + v_{2}
$$
Now to design estimator for $x$, we need the estimated and the actual value of $x$, so we define the estimating error $\tilde{x}$ to be 
$$
\tilde{x} = \hat{x} - x
$$
where $\hat{x} = k_{1}z_{1} + k_{2}z_{2}$. My question is that why $\hat{x}$ is the summation of the two measurements? Shouldn't it be one of the measurements or at least the summation divided by 2 so that we can make the subtraction between the ideal $x$ and observed $\hat{x}$ measurements.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, my point here is that $\hat{x}$ is $x$ doubled. If we assume there is no noise in both measurements $z_{1} \ , z_{2}$, $\tilde{x} = x$ instead of $\tilde{x} = 0$. Taking the average of the two estimates make sense to me not the doubled value.

Comment: @CroCo: I think what you fail to see is that $\hat{x} = k_{1}z_{1} + k_{2}z_{2}$ *can* be simply the average of the two measurements if one chooses $k_1=k_2=1/2$.

Comment: @MattL., what about choosing $k_{1}$ or $k_{2}$ other than half? I'm still not convinced.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, I'm still confused with your answers. Based on what you're saying, there is no rule of determining $\hat{x}$ or I can do whatever calculations with these measurements then assign them to $\hat{x}$. It is not a matter of what I want, it is what is the correct way.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, again you are repeating the same scenario. My question is clear why he did added all measurements together and subtract the total from the true value? Definitely the author is better than me but I'm asking here why he did that. Let's say we have three sensors that measure $z_{i}$ one quantity $x$. $z_{1,2,3} = \{1.1, 1.2, 1.3\}$ and $x = 1$. Which is correct for getting $\tilde{x}$? Is it $\hat{x} = (1.1+1.2+1.3)/3 = 1.2$ so that $\tilde{x} = \hat{x} - x = 0.2$ Or $\hat{x} = (1.1+1.2+1.3) = 3.6$ so that $\tilde{x} = \hat{x} - x = 2.6$?

Comment: @CroCo: He added the _weighted_ measurements together, where the weights are the same if the variances are the same. If the variances are not the same, greater importance are given to the measures with smaller error variance, i.e., the ones which are likely to be more correct. Note that $k_1+k_2=1$ or in your case with three measurements $k_1+k_2+k_3=1$, and, hence, your first estimate is at least valid (and optimal given that the measurements have the same error variance), while for the second you have $k_1+k_2+k_3=3$.

Answer (score 6):

Given measurements
$$\begin{align}
Z_1 &= x + N_1\\
Z_2 &= x + N_2
\end{align}$$
where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are independent zero-mean *Gaussian* random variables
with variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ respectively, it can be shown
that the minimum-mean-square-error (MMSE) estimate of $x$ in terms of $Z_1$ and
$Z_2$ is a *linear function* of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$.  Note that this linearity
is a consequence of the Gaussian assumption; for other kinds of distributions
that might be assumed for the noise variables $N_1$ and $N_2$, the MMSE
estimate is usually not a linear function.

So, let us consider the estimate $\hat{X} = k_0 + k_1Z_1 + k_2Z_2$ for the
unknown parameter $x$.  The mean-square error is thus
$$\begin{align}
E[(\hat{X}-x)^2] &=  E[(k_0 + k_1Z_1 + k_2Z_2 - x)^2]\\
&= E[(k_0 + (k_1+k_2-1)x + k_1N_1+k_2N_2)^2]\\
&= \operatorname{var}(k_1N_1+k_2N_2) + (k_0 + (k_1+k_2-1)x)^2
&{\scriptstyle{\text{because}~E[(Y+a)^2=\operatorname{var}(Y)+(\mu_Y+a)^2}}\\
&\geq \operatorname{var}(k_1N_1+k_2N_2)
\end{align}$$
where equality holds in that last inequality if we choose $k_0=0$ and $k_1+k_2=1$. With a slight change of notation to incorporate these
constraints into our calculations,
let us write 
$$\begin{align}
E[(\hat{X}-x)^2] &= \operatorname{var}(\alpha N_1+(1-\alpha)N_2)\\
&= \alpha^2\sigma_1^2 + (1-\alpha)^2 \sigma_2^2
&{\scriptstyle{\text{because}~N_1, N_2 ~\text{are independent random variables}}}\\
&= \alpha^2(\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2) -2\alpha\sigma_2^2 +  \sigma_2^2
\end{align}$$
where it is easily shown that the minimum value of that quadratic function
of $\alpha$ occurs when we choose
$$\alpha = \frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2} = k_1, \qquad
1-\alpha = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2} = k_2,$$
that is, when the two measurements are afflicted with Gaussian
noise of *different* variances (say with $\sigma_2^2 > \sigma_1^2$),
then the measurement with the *smaller variance* ($N_1$ in this
example) is given *greater weight* 
$k_1=\frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}$
than the measurement with the larger variance ($N_2$ in this case)
which has smaller weight $k_2 = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}$.

When $\sigma_2^2 = \sigma_1^2$, the measurements are given equal weight
$\frac 12$ which is, according to the OP's insistence, the weight that
must be
assigned in all circumstances so as to minimize the mean-square error
because that is the only weighting that makes sense to the OP.

Comment: Judging from a comment in reaction to my comment, the OP seems to start considering weights other than $1/2$, but he is "still not convinced". Let's hope that this answer will bring some light to the darkness.